# Map character to its escaped version

Tags: python

I have this mapping:

```
mapping = {'a': '\a', 'b': '\b', 'f': '\f', 'n': '\n', 'r': '\r', 
            't': '\t', 'v': '\v'}
```

Is there a way to do this without using a dictionary? Perhaps something like:

```
if c in "abfnrtv": c = '\\' + c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> ('\\' + 'a').decode('string-escape')
'\x07'
```

Comment: It's 2.x. On 3.x use `byte`s and `'unicode-escape'` instead. `3>> (b'\\' + b'a').decode('unicode-escape')`
`'\x07'`

Comment: How would you go about doing this in a portable way?

Comment: Depends on how portable you need it. 2.6+ has `bytes`.